# Use exclude in peewee just like Django

Tags: peewee

I want to use `exclude` in peewee just like Django, the code like this

```
# Feature is a model
qs = Feature.exclude(id=1)
```

the exception is

```
AttributeError: type object 'Feature' has no attribute 'exclude'
```

Then i try this

```
qs = Feature.filter(~Feature.get_by_id(1))
```

the exception

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'Feature'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
qs = Feature.select().where(Feature.id != 1)
```

Or

```
qs = Feature.select().where(~(Feature.id == 1))
```

Note that `get_by_id()` is not a chainable method. It simply fetches an object (the equivalent of Django's .get()).